# how to properly grab a url from ie with activex?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

i am trying to grab url of a page that running my activex , I used `DDEMAN` unit but its seems doesn't work in activex here what I have done

```
function Get_URL(Servicio: string): String;
var
  Cliente_DDE: TDDEClientConv;
  S: String;
begin
  Result := '';
  Cliente_DDE := TDDEClientConv.Create(nil);
  with Cliente_DDE do
  begin
    SetLink(Servicio, 'WWW_GetWindowInfo');
    S := RequestData('0xFFFFFFFF');
    Result := S;
    form1.memo1.Lines.Add(Result);
    CloseLink;
  end;
  Cliente_DDE.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
URI: TIdURI;
LinK : String;
Temp: string;
Host,sExt: String;
Path : string;
begin
Link := Get_URL('Iexplore');
Temp := Copy(Link, 1, Pos(',', Link) - 1);
Temp := StringReplace(Temp, '"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);

URI := TIdURI.Create(Temp);
try
Host := URI.Host;
Path := URI.Path;
Host := StringReplace(Host ,'www.', '',[rfReplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]);
sExt  := ExtractFileExt(Host);
Host := Copy(Host, 1, Length(Host) - Length(sExt));
finally
  URI.Free;
end;

end;
```

after running the code its seems that GET_URL function return empty result in `ActiveX` . I tested this code on exe and its working normal . what could be the problem  ? how to properly get a URL that running in IE with ActiveX ?

as remy suggested I tried

```
procedure Tactiveform.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 punk:       IUnknown;
 poo:        IOleObject;
 pcs:        IOleClientSite;
 psp:        IServiceProvider;
 pwb2:       IWebBrowser2;
 pvDoc:      Variant;
 pvElems:    Variant;
 pvElem:     Variant;
 i:          Integer;
 Getsite : string;
begin
punk:=Self.ComObject as IUnKnown;
  if punk.QueryInterface(IOleObject, poo) = S_OK then
  begin
     // Get the client site
     if poo.GetClientSite(pcs) = S_OK then
     begin
        // Have the site, now try to get the Service provider
        if pcs.QueryInterface(IServiceProvider, psp) = S_OK then
        begin
           // Query for WebBrowser2
           if psp.QueryService(IWebBrowserApp, IWebBrowser2, pwb2) = S_OK then
           begin
              memo1.Lines.Add(pwb2.LocationURL);
           end
           else
              memo1.Lines.Add('Didnt get the web browser');
        end
        else
           memo1.Lines.Add('No service provider');
     end
     else
        memo1.Lines.Add('No ole client site');
  end
  else
     memo1.Lines.Add('No ole object');
end;
```

but couldn't compile the code at this line `memo1.Lines.Add(getsite as IWebBrowser2.LocationURL);`

Compiler error fixed

is this good way or maybe I could do it better ?

Comment: Use TWebBrowser interface instead of DDE.

Comment: sorry but how can I use twebbrowser to get IE address url ?

Comment: @MartynA: `TWebBrowser` is a component wrapper around an embedded web browser. In this case, the code is in an ActiveX control that is running inside of an IE browser instance. As such, it can use IE's DOM interfaces to access the browser instance that loaded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ActiveX control's `IOleObject.SetClientSite()` method will receive the browser's `IClientSite` interface, which you can use to retrieve the URL of the HTML page that has loaded your ActiveX control.  There are two different ways you can do that, depending on your version of Internet Explorer.

1. Query the `IClientSite` for `IServiceProvider`, then call `IServiceProvider.QueryService()` to get an `IWebBrowser2`, then you can read the `IWebBrowser2.LocationURL` property.
2. Query the `IClientSite` for `IHTMLDocument2`, then read the `IHTMLDocument2.URL` property.

See the following MSN article for more details:

[Accessing the Object Model from Within an ActiveX Control](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172763)

Comment: I am trying to apply what you suggested . I update the code in my question

Comment: The problem you describe about getting a compiler error does not match the code you have shown for `Button1Click()`. What is the actual error?  Also, have you tried the 2nd approach I mentioned above? You might want to do that anyway, since that returns the URL of the document that your ActiveX is on, rather than the URL that the browser is displaying, which may be different if HTML frames are involved, for instance.

Comment: error gone is already my bad I should read pwb2.LocationURL instead of IWebBrowser2.LocationURL  , also I will try the second approach too thank you very much